# How can I include 'ng2-summernote' module in my angular cli (beta17) project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, summernote

**Hey fellow programmers**

I'm currently failing on integrating an angular2 directive - installed with npm - in my angular cli project.

**What I did so far:**

I clone the following git repo: https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-cli-seed

I was able to run the app with 'ng serve' without problems. Now, I want to use the Summernote WYSIWYG editor. Thank god, there is already an integration for angular 2 which can be found on the following page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-summernote

I installed this via 'npm install ng2-summernote' in my projet directory. It also shows up in my 'node_modules'-folder.

From now on, I dont know what to do. What i tried was the following code

(home.module.ts)

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Ng2Summernote } from 'ng2-summernote/ng2-summernote';
import { homeRouting } from "./home.routing";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

@NgModule({
imports: [
homeRouting
],
declarations: [
HomeComponent,
Ng2Summernote
]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

(home.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2Summernote } from 'ng2-summernote/ng2-summernote';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass']
})

export class HomeComponent {

constructor(summernote: Ng2Summernote) {
summernote.lang = 'de-DE';
summernote.airMode = true;
}

say_hello(){
alert('Hello World')
}

}
```

(home.component.html)

```
<div class="section ribbon white-ribbon center">
<h2>
Welcome
</h2>

<button  (click)="say_hello()" class="btn waves-effect btn-large red darken-2" type="submit" name="action">HELLO
<i class="material-icons right">language</i>
</button>

</div>

<ng2-summernote></ng2-summernote>
```

Is there anyone who can detect my fault? In the browser, I only get the following error message:

```
metadata_resolver.js:275
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Ng2Summernote' declared by the module 'HomeModule'
```

I appreciate any kind of answers. I#m fairly new to Angular 2/CLI. :-)